# how to use subdomain with link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, link-to

I have issue and I can't fix it.

This code in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :admin do
    constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
      root to: "home#index"
      concern :supportable do
        resources :supports, only: [:new, :create]
      end
      resources :users, concerns: :supportable do
        collection do
          get 'search'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to use link_to in Ruby on Rail for link. example : `<%= link_to admin_users_path do %>` but in view show `href="/admin/users"`. if I click to link redirect to `http://admin.example.com/admin/users`. But this link incorrect. I want to redirect link `http://admin.example.com/users`.

How to use link_to but render to html as `href="/users"`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with `path:'/'` in `namespace`, work for me:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :admin, path: '/' do
    constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```